# rails - multiple paths for a search form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm implementing the website. I got a problem for a search form. I upload my code, and what i want to ask is how to set the search 'path' through 'index' and 'historical' on homes_controller
Below, my code:

**app/controllers/homes_controller**

```
 def index
    @homes = Home.where(:category => 1).reverse
 end

 def historical
    @homes = Home.where(:category => 2).reverse
 end
```

**app/views/layouts/application.html.erb**

Below, this code is temporary code for now. I should change it.

```
<%= form_tag(homes_path, :method => 'get', id: "search-form" do %>
    <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], placeholder: "검색" %>
    <%= submit_tag "검색", :name => nil %>
  <% end %>
```

Comment: is your search box for a global search OR independent to each controller action?

Answer (score 0):

Am not sure what you are supposed to do here

But as per the question - I can give a solution to your problem

Keep an instance variable in your controller actions - like this

app/controllers/homes_controller

```
 def index
    @homes = Home.where(:category => 1).reverse
    @search_path = "path you want to give" 
 end

 def historical
    @homes = Home.where(:category => 2).reverse
    @search_path = "path you want to give" 
 end
```

and in your layout you can use it like this

app/views/layouts/application.html.erb

```
<%= @search_path.present? %>

  <%= form_tag(@search_path, :method => 'get', id: "search-form" do %>
    <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], placeholder: "검색" %>
    <%= submit_tag "검색", :name => nil %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```